# Changed properties of application by accident what is default: FireFox

Tags: unity, firefox, shortcut-keys, launcher

I was trying to create a custom shortcut so that I could use multiple profiles with FireFox, however when I created the "link" it was a symbolic link so I edited what I thought was a "shortcut" but was editing the real application launcher.

Q:           What are the default settings for Firefox? Or How can I reset without losing everything?

What happened:
I wanted to use multiple profiles so I went to the applications folder and right clicked "Firefox"> "make new link" then I preceded to edit the link thinking it was a shortcut but in fact it was a symbolic link.

Now I just need to know what is the default info for firefox or how can I reset without losing everything, because when I open firefox now I get an error that it is already open or a completely different browser opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you edited the original file? It would have asked you your `sudo` password.

**A.** If it did asked you, and you're talking about `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` that was modified, here's a lesson:

> *Don't use your sudo password if you're not sure of what you're doing*

**B.** If you never needed `sudo` admin password, then the original file should be accessible (read-only) in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`, you should copy that file's content in `~/.share/applications/firefox.desktop`

**C.** If none of the above is right, you might just make a "default typical" desktop file:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Comment=Browse the web
> Name=Firefox
> Exec=/usr/bin/firefox
> Icon=firefox
> StartupNotify=false
> Categories=Network;
> Type=Application
> ```

**D.** Ultimately, you could save your profile, purge firefox, and reinstall it clean.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I ended up editing it with sudo privilege I wasnt able to make the link in the first place without, but like I said I thought I was editing a "shortcut" not a symlink...